# trace variable access (c/c++)?

Tags: c++, c

Not sure if feasible... I am reading a large software code, and sometimes feel lost when tracing how certain variable is accessed.

It would be great if there is tool/method to trace that.

More specifically, suppose I have the following class.

```
class A
{
  public:
    int _a;
};

...
```

and whenever

```
... = ...->_a;
```

during runtime, I would like to print out FILE and LINE. Thank you for the suggestion.

P.S., I could grep all "->_a" appearances, but that is also pretty hard to sort out.

Comment: You can do something similar to this by firing up a debugger and setting breakpoints.

Comment: Or by making variables `private` and just adding tracing code to the accessor functions.

Comment: Think of that, just making the variable `private` and running a compiler over the code will likely report exactly what you ask for, file and line.

Comment: Can you provide any additional information like SO, compiler, compiler version, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
class A
{
  public:
    int _a;
};
```

You could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Integer
{
public:
    Integer(int value) : value(value)
    {
    }

    operator int()
    {
        std::cout << "Integer called\n";
        return value;
    }
private:
    int value;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() : _a(5) {}
    Integer _a;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a._a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Following your example:

- Create a class and provide an operator for implicit conversion;
- Substitute your member variable for this new class.

The implicit conversion operator will do the work.

It will print:

> Integer called
>
> 5

A tip: never let a member variable be public. Always provide an accessor method.

**Edit**

Sorry, I forgot about **FILE** and **LINE**:

I didn't find a way to inject **LINE** or **FILE** because the implicit cast will be done at runtime while macro substitution under preprocessing.

What you can do it is to put a breakpoint at implicit conversion function, as pointed by @veer, and manually trace each calling.

**Edit 2**

At least it is possible to see the call stack at runtime.

On Linux this can be done through [execinfo](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) and on Windows through [StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack).

Comment: That is interesting, but where to inject "__FILE__" and "__LINE__"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) or [Source Navigator](http://sourcenav.berlios.de/) to find all occurrences. This is static analysis, not runtime, but easier than grep.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most powerful tools to debug C code is GDB. For your specific need, you can make use of watch/awatch/rwatch commands in GDB to identify points when your variable is accessed (read/write). Once program execution stops at those points, you could use `print` to either check or set the value of that variable.

Refer to [this link](http://www.technochakra.com/debugging-types-of-data-breakpoints-in-gdb/) for further clarifications.